# Prevent direct access to PDF files - Nginx

Tags: linux, pdf, nginx, server

Lately I changed a server for my website. Before I used Apache server. Now my website works on Nginx server. That is why I can't use `.htaccess` any longer.

I would like to prevent users from opening some pdf files by typing the link to the files in the browser. I want them to be able to open the files by clicking on the links to the files from my website. So far I used the code below; it works well when it comes to preventing hotlinking images, but it doesn't prevent direct access to pdf files.

```
location ~ /folder/with/pdffiles/(.+\.(?:jpg|pdf|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ic$

valid_referers none blocked server_names *.mydomain.com mydomain.* ~\.mydomain\.;
       if ($invalid_referer) {
         return 444;
        }
        try_files $uri @ghost;
}
```

Comment: Can you copy the rest of your location directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could do something like:

```
if ($http_referer = "") { return 403; }
```

Inside of your nginx location, if conditions are not a recommended thing to do (see [If is Evil](http://x.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)).

The standard practise today is to place restricted files outside the web-server root folder (doesn't matter what it is - Apache or nginx), and serve the files via a server-side script that can do anything you want – not only check the referrer, but perhaps a user session or authentication.